# Multiple database select in PHP, but print IDs separately

Tags: php

I want to perform a multiple database select, but print IDs separately.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM peron, peronmedia WHERE peronmedia.PID=5" and peron.ID=5"; $xc = mysqli_query($baglanti, $sql); $rs=mysqli_fetch_array($xc);

echo $rs["peron.PID"];
echo $rs["peronmedia.ID"];
```

But this code doesn't work.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Define Alias name after table is better way to understand and have to specify the database name otherwise it will rise `field list is ambiguous`

```
$sql = "SELECT pr.PID AS PERON_PID,pm.ID AS PERONMEDIA_ID FROM peron pr, peronmedia pm WHERE databasename1.peronmedia.PID=5 AND databasename2.peron.ID=5"; 
$xc = mysqli_query($baglanti, $sql);
$rs=mysqli_fetch_array($xc);

echo $rs["PERON_PID"];
echo $rs["PERONMEDIA_ID"];
```